# What happens on allocating with "new []" and deleting with just "delete"

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, new-operator

Okay, so i was experimenting with pointers in C++, as i have started to code again after almost an year and a half break(School Stuff). So please spare me if this seems naive to you, i am just rusting off.

Anyways, i was screwing around with pointers in VS 2019, and i noticed something that started to bug me.

This is the code that i wrote:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* i = new int[4];
    *i = 323;
    *(i + 1) = 453;
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(i + 1) << std::endl;
    delete i;
}
```

Something seems odd right? Dont worry, that delete is intentional, and is kindof the point of this question. Now I expected it to do some memory mishaps, since this is not the way we delete an array on the heap, **BUT** to my surprise, it did not(I did this in both Debug and Release and had the same observation)

*Allocating the array:*
[image]

*First Modification:*
[image]

*Second Modification*
[image]

Now i was expecting some sort of mishap at delete, since i did not delete it the way it is supposed to be deleted. BUT

***Deleting Incorrectly***

[image]

Now on another run i actually used the delete operator **correctly** and it did the same thing:

[image]

Now i got the same results when i tried to allocate with malloc and use delete to free it.

So my question is - Why does my code not mess up? I mean if this is how it works, I could just use delete (pointer) to wipe the entire array.

The gist of my question is ***"What does new operator do under the hood?"***

Comment: int main() {
 int* i = new int[4];

 *i = 323; 
 *(i + 1) = 453;

 std::cout << *i << std::endl;
 std::cout << *(i + 1) << std::endl;

 delete i;

 return 0;
}

Comment: Crashes on my machine.  Both what I saw, and what you saw, are reasonable outcomes due to undefined behavior.  Between the two, I think I got the better behavior.

Comment: Okay, So i tested the code on clang, and it just deleted the first integer in the array, the rest were untouched

Comment: What happens is _undefined_.

Comment: @mitesh It probably overwrote the first integer in debug mode. It has no bearing.

Comment: The problem is far more pronounced (and obvious) when the object stored in the vector has a destructor.

Comment: Our old friend [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). *Anything* is allowed - the program is simply invalid.

Comment: Try using a class with a destructor instead of `int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What happens on allocating with “new []” and deleting with just “delete”

The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Now I expected it to do some memory mishaps

Your expectation is misguided. Undefined behaviour does not guarantee mishaps in memory or otherwise. Nothing about the behaviour of the program is guaranteed.

> I mean if this is how it works

This is how you observed it to "work". It doesn't mean that it will necessarily always work like that. Welcome to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay so i tested it on clang, and it just deleted the first element in the array(as it should), So is this behavior compiler specific?

Comment: `(as it should)` There is no behaviour that the program "should" have when the behaviour is undefined. `So is this behavior compiler specific?` Anything, can affect undefined behaviour. This includes compiler, operating system, CPU, phase of the moon and your neighbor. Also, behaviour can be different even under perfectly identical conditions.

Comment: @mitesh It is undefined which means compilers can do whatever they want. The behavior may change from one compiler release to another, it may change by simply using different compiler flags. It may change for the same compiler version using the same flags but on a different architecture/OS etc.

Comment: @mitesh to answer your question directly, yes it's compiler specific. It can also be day-specific, weather specific, or the compiler can even emit code that uses launch codes to blow up a foreign nation. All of these are no more valid or invalid than the other. That's what undefined behavior is.